# How to remove remote branch only from my local git?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I know the command `git push -d <remote> <branch_name>`

I want to delete remote branch only from **my local git env**. The command above removes remote branch from my local and remote github also.

However, if I had removed remote branch **in github** directly like this,

[image]

there is no branch named `feature/search` in remote anymore, the command fails.

So, how can I remove remote branch in my local without interacting remote github?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+remote-tracking+branch

Comment: `git branch -d -r` to delete a local remote-tracking branch.

Comment: ^----- this. Also one needs to give fuller name to the "local" version of the remote branch. Using the OP's branch one would need `git branch -d -r origin/feature/search`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/7409008).**

---

You can use `git branch -D` or `git branch -d` for deleting a branch locally.

from the [official doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--d)

```
  -d
  --delete
  Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in HEAD if 
  no upstream was set with --track or --set-upstream-to.

  -D
  Shortcut for --delete --force.
```

---

In your case, it should be,

```
  git branch -d feature/search
```

Comment: The linked answer works. The 2nd half of this answer does not address the OP's issue - as the operation checked the remote git repo and fails once it discovers the remote branch no longer exists (stopping and not cleaning up the "local" tracking of the remote branch)